# Remove all the elements that occur in 1 list from another c++

Tags: c++, list

Let's say I have two lists, l1 and l2. I want to perform l1 - l2, which returns l1 with any elements that are also elements of l2 removed.

I can think of a naive loop approach to doing this, but that is going to be really inefficient. What is an efficient way of doing this in c++?

As an example, if I have l1 = [1,2,6,8] and l2 = [2,8], l1 - l2 should return [1,6]

thanks you guys

Comment: You could sort both lists first, which would make the removal process much faster. Do you care about the ordering of items in the returned list?

Comment: The standard algorithms provide `set_difference`...

Comment: @ CrazyJugglerDrummer: I dont care about the order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the order matter? Will the list contain duplicates?

If not I'd recommend doing a [set_difference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/)

Just a heads up though, if you do have duplicates, I think set_difference only removes the first occurrence of the duplicated elements you want to remove.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in amortized linear time with a hash set.

First, create an empty set, H. Loop over L1 and insert each element into H.

Then, loop over L2. For each element of L2, append to a vector if and only if that element is not in H.

If H provides constant-time insertion and access, and you use a constant-time-append structure to store your temporary result, the overall algorithm is linear in the sum of the lists' sizes.

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach takes `O(n^2)`, because you have to compare each element form the first list with each element form the second list.

A slightly better approach is to sort the lists (`O(n*log(n))`) and then iterate through them. If they are sorted, you only need one pass, so time is `O(n*log(n))`.

An even better approach is to insert all elements of the second list in a `std::unordered_set` (`O(n)`), iterate through each of the elements of the first list (`O(n)`) and check if it's contained in the set (`O(1)` amortized time). This should do it. - This works only if you have no duplicates.

Comment: If you have duplicates, use `unordered_map` to keep a count of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it the O(n^2) naive way for the unsorted case you can do that with a little bit of `<algorithm>` and `std::bind` (or boost if that's not an option) trickery:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
  std::list<std::string> a = {"foo", "bar", "baz", "woof"},
                         b = {"baz", "bar", "random other thing"};

  a.erase(std::remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::bind(std::equal_to<std::list<std::string>::iterator>(), b.end(), std::bind(std::find<std::list<std::string>::iterator, std::string>, b.begin(), b.end(), std::placeholders::_1))), a.end());

  std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```